# Discord command not entirely functional, any ideas?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I wrote a DM command for my discord bot, it only partly works because the user can only see one word of the message, any ideas on how to fix that?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def dm(ctx, target: discord.User, message=None):
    author = ctx.author
    mention = ctx.message.author.mention
    await target.send(message)

    await ctx.send("{0} has recieved your message, {1} :envelope:".format(target.mention, mention))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [keyword-only arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).

```
async def dm(ctx, target: discord.User, *, message)
```

(It defaults to a blank str if no arg is passed)